# Definition of homogeneous Sobolev spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, harmonic-analysis, fractional-calculus

As we know the inhomogeneous Sobolev space (we only consider $s>0$)
$${H}^{s}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)=\left\{f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^n):\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\xi|^{2 s}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^{2} \mathrm{d} \xi<\infty\right\}$$
I am quite confused by the homogeneous one $\dot H^s$ which consists of functions with the following quantity is bounded
$$
\|f\|_{\dot{H}^{s}}=\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\xi|^{2 s}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^{2} \mathrm{d} \xi\right)^{1 / 2}\label{1}\tag{*}$$

There are several definitions of $\dot H^s$ (I use a subscript to distinguish them).

1. In  L. Grafakos, Modern Fourier analysis, he defines
   $$\dot{H}_G^{s}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)=\left\{f \in \mathscr{S}^{\prime}/\mathscr{P}:  \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\xi|^{2 s}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^{2} \mathrm{d} \xi<\infty\right\}$$
   Here $\mathscr{S}^{\prime}/\mathscr{P}$ is the equivalent class of distributions modulo polynomials (that is, we identify two distributions whose difference is a polynomial). Then \eqref{1} is a norm.
2. Maybe there is a more natural one by

$$\dot H^s_N(\mathbb{R}^n)=\text{completion of }\left\{f\in \mathscr{S}:\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\xi|^{2 s}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^{2} \mathrm{d} \xi<\infty\right\}\text{ under the norm \eqref{1}}$$

My questions are

1. Is $\dot H_G^s$ complete under \eqref{1}?
2. Is $\dot H^s_N=\dot H_G^s$?

Add after Michael's comment: There is another version in *H. Bahouri, J.-Y. Chemin,  R. Danchin, Fourier analysis and nonlinear partial differential equations.*
They define
$$
\dot{H}_B^{s}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)=\left\{f \in \mathscr{S}^{\prime}: \hat{f} \in L_{\operatorname{loc}}^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right) \text { and } \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\xi|^{2 s}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^{2} \mathrm{d} \xi<\infty\right\}$$
The reason why they include  $ \hat{f} \in L_{\operatorname{loc}}^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ arise from problems with understanding the meaning of $|\xi|^s \hat f$ if one only knows that $\hat f\in \mathscr{S}'$

This definition makes more sense by restricting $\hat f\in L_{loc}$. However, it is known that for $s < n/2$,   $\dot H^s_B$ is a Hilbert space with $(*)$, while, when $\dot H^{s}_B$ is not complete when $s\geq n/2$. I am trying to avoid this definition because it is not complete.

Comment: Your first definition does not seem to quite make sense, at least not without further explanation. If all you know is that f is a tempered distribution, how would you define the integral (even allowing for an infinite value)? You would need to know $\hat f$ is locally integrable or something like that.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy    I add one paragraph. I hope it can address your concern. My question is still there.

Comment: I suggest to have a look at Chapter 2 of "An Introduction to the mathematical theory of the Navier-Stokes equation" by P. Galdi. He defines and study homogenuous Sobolev spaces for general $p$ but withouth using the Fourier transform.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I did not find the definition of fractional derivative. It seems he only deals with s being some integer.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But he explains well the density results and the need for the polynomial correction.